# Next JS 13: How to fix JSON caching issue on website after session

Tags: next.js, browser-cache

I'm using next: "^13.3.0", react: "18.2.0", with the following next.Config

```
experimental: {
    appDir: true,
    isrMemoryCacheSize: 0,
  }
```

I've deployed my website on AWS via AWS Amplify with the default build config for production.

**The issue is** whenever I go back to the tab with my website open after some time like an hour or so, or after a session, some JSON appears on the website, seems like some caching of build by nextJS for faster loading. Not sure how to fix it. This happens in both mobile and PC browsers. Pic attached below for reference. The screenshot is of the browser(Chrome) in my PC.

[Image of browser when issue occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00KWQ.jpg)

How to fix this issue?

I tried to clear cache with experimental feature of **isrMemoryCacheSize: 0.**

But the issue continues.

Answer (score 2):

I think this has to do with Next's prefetch feature. If the `Next-Router-Prefetch: 1` header is present Next seems to return a state tree instead of HTML. If your service caches the result without varying on this header, it results in being shown in the browser.

For example, you go to `/` and Next returns HTML. Next prefetches `/about` and gets a state tree. Now if you go to `/about` (with a page refresh) you will see the state tree.

You might look into the cache settings of Amplify to solve this issue. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON that you are seeing is the Next.js build manifest. This manifest is used by Next.js to cache the build files so that they can be loaded more quickly when the page is refreshed.

There are a few ways to fix this issue. One way is to use the `next.config.js` file to disable the build manifest entirely. To do this, add the following line to your `next.config.js` file:

```
disableManifest: true
```

Another way to fix this issue is to use the `cache-bust` option in the `next.config.js` file. This option will add a unique hash to the end of the build manifest, which will prevent the browser from caching the manifest. To use the `cache-bust` option, add the following line to your `next.config.js` file:

```
cacheBust: true
```

To permanently get rid of the problem which in my case is caused when I redirect to a different route and try coming back, here is what my configurations look like.

```
const nextConfig = {
  disableManifest: true,
  cacheBust: true,
  experimental: {
    appDir: true
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

This will disable the build manifest and add a unique hash to the end of the build manifest, which will prevent the browser from caching the manifest.

Comment: Hello, I'm experiencing the same issue. Is there any updated solution about this? Next.JS says:

Invalid next.config.js options detected:
Unrecognized key(s) in object: 'disableManifest', 'cacheBust'